# window.location.replace unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a button that when clicked, is initiating a POST request to my API.
I then want to take the response URL from the API call and redirect to it.

This is what my JS look like:

```
function submitPassowrd(url) {
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send();
let u = xhr.responseText
if (xhr.status === 200) {
    window.location.replace(u);
    return false
}
return false
}
```

The problem is, that instead of redirecting to the URL from the API response, it is concatenating it to the base URL. So if the URL is http://example.com, it will just add it like: http://127.0.0.1:8081/http://example.com.

That said, when I am using a hard-coded URL, it works just fine and redirects me properly to the website provided in window.location.replace. For example:

```
function submitPassowrd(url) {
let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify();
let u = xhr.responseText
if (xhr.status === 200) {
    window.location.replace('http://example.com'); // <<<<<<< hard-coded URL
    return false
}
return false
}
```

Also, I tried using window.location.href which caused the exact same behavior.

What can explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `window.location.href` or simply `window.location` instead of `window.location.replace` for this use case imho.

That been said, the possible explanation for `.replace` behavior is that the url is encoded and thus not perceived as a url (rather a string only) and thus gets concatenated to the current page url. You can console.log the output of `u` to see if the returned string is encoded?

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention, but I also tried using window.location.href. Same behaviour.

Comment: i updated the answer, please try window.location only and also console.log the output of `u`

Comment: The output of `u` is just the URL itself (as a string)

Comment: try window.location only

Comment: Same goes for window.location

Comment: then the output is not url string, plz share the exact output of console.log?

Comment: or possibly check the response of the ajax, as console.log will convert the encoded string to a normal one too for output

Comment: plz confirm from the ajax response (in dev tools), also try decodeURI on returned string

Comment: It just say: `main.js:7 XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/validate/frVYm".`. tried decodeURI, didn't work as well.

Comment: what is the response ?

Comment: Where should I see the response?

Comment: dev tools > network > click on the ajax file and then on right you will see headers, preview, response

Comment: the action should happen after opening the dev tools and network tab

Comment: `access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
content-length: 25
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 17:24:26 GMT
server: uvicorn
vary: Origin`